# jsGrid: how to reference a row directly?

Tags: jsgrid

I am using [jsGrid](http://js-grid.com/).

Given a row index, how do I access the items in a row of a jsGrid table directly from Javascript?

Comment: You've been here long enough to know that your question, at its current state, is too broad

Comment: I suppose row index and item index should be the same. So you can get an item like `$("#grid").jsGrid("option", "data")[rowIndex]`.

Comment: Thanks. Just what I need.